# htaccess 301 redirect everything except subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wish to redirect an entire domain except for 1 subdomain to another site.

I'm trying to get:

http://domain.com

http://www.domain.com

to redirect to another website/domain.

I want subdomain.domain.com to remain unaffected.

So far I have only managed to get either the www or the non www versions to redirect but not both at the same time.

Any assistance would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.another-domain/$1 [R=301,L]
```